# Node.JS Typescript Rollup Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, plugins, node-modules, rollupjs

**NodeJS: v18.7.0**

**NPM: 8.15.0**

`rollup.config.js`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';

import tsConfig from './tsconfig.json';

const config = [
    {
        input: "index.ts",
        output: [{ file: "build/index.js", sourcemap: true }],
        plugins: [
            typescript(
                {
                    sourceMap: tsConfig.compilerOptions.sourceMap
                }
            )
        ]
    },
    {
        input: 'build/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: "build/index.d.ts", "format": "es" }],
        plugins: [
            dts(
                {
                    compilerOptions: {
                        baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl
                    }
                }
            )
        ]
    },
]

export default config;
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "@rollup/plugin-typescript"
            }
        ]
   }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.4",
    "rollup": "^2.77.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

```
$ n run build

> webapi@1.0.0 build
> tsc --project tsconfig.build.json && npm run rollup


> webapi@1.0.0 rollup
> rollup -c


index.ts → build/index.js...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
url (imported by index.ts)
path (imported by index.ts)
http-errors (imported by index.ts)
express (imported by index.ts, routes/index.ts, routes/healthchecks.ts, routes/api.ts)
compression (imported by index.ts)
helmet (imported by index.ts)
cors (imported by index.ts)
cookie-parser (imported by index.ts)
morgan (imported by index.ts)
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
../infrastructure/db.ts (5:9)
3: import config from 'config'
4: export class Database {
5:   private static _pool: Pool;
             ^
6:   static init() {
7:     try {
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:198:30)
    at Module.error (/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12543:16)
    at Module.tryParse (/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12920:25)
    at Module.setSource (/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12825:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22267:20)

npm ERR! Lifecycle script `rollup` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: webapi@1.0.0 
npm ERR!   at location: /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/webapi 
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: webapi@1.0.0 
npm ERR!   at location: /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/webapi
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, apparently, `@rollup/plugin-typescript` is broken.

Switching to `rollup-plugin-typescript` fixed the issue for me.

---

**Update**: I switched back to `@rollup/plugin-typescript` a while ago, the problem does not occur anymore (using v10.0.1). Whatever it was, it seems like they fixed it.

Comment: `rollup-plugin-typescript` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-typescript) in favor of `@rollup/plugin-typescript`.

Comment: still i am facing the same issuee